unable to apply coupon using darryldecode in laravel
I'm trying to apply coupon using darryldecode library
public function applyDiscount(Request $request)
{

    $condition = new \Darryldecode\Cart\CartCondition(array(
        'name' => 'voucher',
        'type' => 'discount',
        'target' => 'subtotal', 
        'value' => '12.5%',
    ));
    \Cart::condition($condition);
}

but still total amount is same.

reference:
https://packagist.org/packages/darryldecode/cart
https://github.com/darryldecode/laravelshoppingcart/blob/master/tests/CartConditionsTest.php

any solution Thanks

what is your laravel version and the lib version, please? have u read that "When adding a condition on a cart bases, the 'target' should have value of 'subtotal' or 'total'. "

@francisco My laravel version is 8, i tried with toatal also but value  change was not reflected in cart total

right in the packagist says:
"For Laravel 5.1~: composer require "darryldecode/cart:~2.0"
For Laravel 5.5, 5.6, or 5.7~, 9:
composer require "darryldecode/cart:~4.0" or composer require "darryldecode/cart"`This doen't work for 8

This pack won't work in laravel 8. Check the docs in the title of git.

i'm using "darryldecode/cart": "^4.2" in my application

@user3653474 try update laravel 8 to 9 and say something

Cart::session($userID)->condition($condition2); this code was missing now it's working Thanks
